# Use of preposition in in question a sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions, questions

Which of the following sentences are correct regarding to know the preference about car.

What is your preference **to** car?

OR

What is your preference **on** car?

Please let me know the meaning of both sentences.

Comment: Neither of your prepositions work at all, but idiomatically the construction is relatively unlikely even with a *valid* preposition *(**for, among, between,...**)*. Most people would probably ask *What car do you prefer?* (or more formally, *What is your preferred car?*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of them is correct. The appropriate preposition here would be for or among or between.

> What is your preference for cars?
> What is your preference among cars?
> What is your preference between cars?

Note that I have made car plural here. I would have to say none of these sounds very natural to me and I would probably change the whole sentence

> Which cars do you prefer?

Comment: What is your preference for cars [over trains]? It doesn't make sense to me without the comparison...

Comment: As I said none of them is ideal and for is perhaps the worst of the options.

Comment: I've seen a sentence What's the difference between men's and women's preference on cars? Actually I want to know its meaning.

Comment: The sentence you have seen is not correct I am afraid.